# Terminal find using download time

Tags: shell, find

I was wondering if there is a way to find files using the `find` tool in Terminal based on file's download time. I know there are options for access (`-amin`), creation (`-cmin`), and modified (`-mmin`), but can't figure out a way to filter files based on time they were downloaded.

I checked and the creation time was not same as it's download time. If `find` can't do it, what's my other best option.

Comment: Some clients change timestamps to match those found on the server.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *creation time* in Unix; ctime is the *inode change time*.

Your best bet is to use the *time of last modification*, aka mtime, which gives you the time the download ended. If you must know when the download started, you need to record the date prior to the download. If you need the download duration, you subtract the end time from the start time. There are tons of questions how to compute the length between two time stamps. Don't ask another :-)

**EDIT**: It appears your downloader (which one? Why didn't you specify it?) changes the time stamps to match the original. You can read its documentation if it has an option to suppress this. You could also find out if it can write the file to stdout and redirect it (e.g. `wget -O - http://file > file`) This will always force the mtime to be current.

Comment: Modification date isn't the same as time when download finished. I'm checking on files I downloaded today and the dates are pretty much random, some even months old.

Comment: @user14492 : Jens is right on his definitions. All *nix work this way. There must be another explanation for what you are seeing. Some `ftp` clients might copy over the remote files timestamps. Otherwise, you'll have to give us a reproducible problem, including OS/version, transfer client name and version, etc. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry, I didn't give all details. I'm using Safari, on OS X 10.10.5.